# use of だとつい...で…… in these sentence

Tags: words

students visits her teacher, to deliver some food. She has known him since she was little

> speaker response carelessly attaching ~ちゃん to her name
>
> student「先生、また『ちゃん』って言ってます」
>
> 先生「え？　あ、あぁ　すまんね。家**だとつい**癖で……」
>
> speaker's response to the student saying that she came here to deliver
> food
>
> 先生「いつもすまないね。気を遣ってもらって……」
>
> student「気にしないでください。先生には昔からお世話になってますから」
>
> 先生「ありがとう。男やもめ**だとつい**簡単に済ませてしまいがちで……」
>
> 先生は奥さんを十二年ほど前に亡くしてから、ずっと一人で暮らしていた。

家だとつい癖で - if it's at home, unconscious habit (cause?) ....

男やもめだとつい簡単に済ませてしまいがちで - i find it hard to use ~だと as a quote for ~ nor the "if ~ is the case usage" for this sentence.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern **XだとY** can simply be thought of as "**if** (or "**when**", or "**as**") X, **then** Y."

> **Example:** 家だと酔う　＝　if/when I'm home, (then) I'm drunk (or "I get drunk").

**つい** is, as you noted, a phrase indicating carelessness or unconscious action, done (or left undone) by accident.

> **Example:** 家だとつい酔う　＝　if/when I'm home, (then) I unintentionally end up getting drunk.

so the first example of these two phrases together, **家だとつい癖で**  (『ちゃん』って言ってしまう)means as you thought

> "when I'm home, (I just say "chan") by habit"

**thanks to Naruto for pointing out the unspoken verb phrase, which means that 癖 is not being used as a simple noun as in "it's a habit", but is being used adverbially as 癖で "by habit"**

... or more naturally in English "At home, it just comes out/slips out."

the second phrase in which this pairing is used, **男やもめだとつい簡単に済ませてしまいがち**, the **だと** uses the "**as**" meaning, since being a widower is not a temporary state:

> "As a widower, I unintentionally have a tendency to get it over with
> simply."

("it" being eating or making something to eat, in this context)

a more natural English phrase might be "As a widower I tend to eat simply, without thinking about it."

Comment: で after 癖 is a particle, not the te-form of だ. 癖で = "by habit". There is a omitted verb after it (『ちゃん』って言ってしまう).

Comment: ah. Or for example 癖で(呼んでしまう）？ thank you. I will edit to reflect this...